# Supremum of scaled Brownian motion shifted by bounded smooth function

Tags: pr.probability, stochastic-processes

I would like to ask the following question:

Let $e$ be a nonnegative, bounded, smooth function from $\left[  0,1\right]  $
to $\left[  0,1\right]  $, such that $e\left(  0\right)  =e\left(  1\right)
=0$. Let $r>0$ be a given constant. Further, let

$X_{s}=\dfrac{1}{1+s}W_{s}-\sqrt{r}e\left(  \dfrac{1}{1+s}\right)$

for $s\geq0$, where $\left\{  W_{s}:s\geq0\right\}  $ is a standard Brownian
motion (starting at $W_{0}=0$). Find or bound the probability of the event
$A_{z}=\left\{  \omega:\sup\nolimits_{s\geq0}\left\vert X_{s}\right\vert \geq
z\right\}  $ for $z>0$.

Any point to reference or suggestion is appreciated. Thank you.

Regards,

Chee

Comment: @ Chee : What is the purpose of the presence of constant $r$ in $X$ definition ? Also would you add some motivation for this queston ? Regards

Comment: Does Girsanov's theorem not get you what you want?

Comment: @ The Bridge: Thank you very much for your reply. This question is the transformed question on the supremum of a Browian bridge shifted by a smooth function. The $r$ acts as a parameter and we will be interested in the bahavior of $sup|X_s|$ when $r$ is large. The best would be an analytic expression or recursive formula of the probability of that event involving $r$

Comment: @Nate Eldredge: Thank you.  The Girsanov's theorem only removes the drift term but not the diffusion coefficient. Besides, one still needs to compute the new measure in order to get the probability. Maybe I missed something but would love to hear more of your suggestions.

Comment: @Chee: When you're asked for motivation, I think people are hoping to a bigger context, basically to distinguish it from a homework question. If you frame your question "I've been working on the interaction of Brownian motion and Galois theory, and have arrived at the following question about Brownian bridges" or something, people will probably be much more willing to think about answering it. (see the FAQ)

Comment: @Chee: time change will get rid of the time-dependence in the diffusion. Think again about Nate Eldrege's suggestion.

Comment: @AnthonyQuas: Thank you for warmly point this out. I have got a bound on this probability when $r$ is large (which is $1+o \left(r\right)$ for any fixed $z >0$). However, deriving an analytic expression for this probability is beyond my capability. This is not a homework problem but one I encountered doing research. Basically, it is equivalent to the distribution of the p-value of the Kolmogorov-Smirnov test on if a set of iid sample is from one compoment when one knows that the sample is from a two-component smooth mixture distribution. Thank you again.

Comment: @oferzeitouni: Thank you for suggesting the time change. I will try both successively!